# Pandas groupby a column and set max value in other column as 1 else 0

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, max

I have a data frame as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'unique_id':['x','x' , 'y', 'y'], 'chk':[5, 6, -4, -5], 'score':[5.52363, 6.73939, 7.53637, 3.08375]})
```

I want to group by `'unique_id'` column and look for the max value in `'score'` column and set the max value as 1 and others as 0.

I tried `df['result'] = df.groupby('unique_id').apply(lambda x: [x.score.idxmax()])`

But it gives me null values instead. My expected output is

```
unique_ID  chk  score  result
x          5   5.52363   0
x          6   6.73939   1
y         -4   7.53637   1
y         -5   3.08375   0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) to check if the values is the **max** and [`Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) to get 0 or 1

```
df['result'] = df['score'].eq(df.groupby('unique_id')
                                .score
                                .transform('max')).astype(int)
print(df)
  unique_id  chk    score  result
0         x    5  5.52363       0
1         x    6  6.73939       1
2         y   -4  7.53637       1
3         y   -5  3.08375       0
```